# Assign on() event handler to appended element (using uploadifive)

Tags: jquery, ajax, event-handling

I am using uploadifive and the actual image upload is working fine, plus I have amended to display the uploaded images on successful upload. However, I would like the user to be able to remove the image if it is incorrect and as the images are appended to a div I know I need to bind the on() event handler to the images that were not originally in the DOM but I can't work out how to do this. My current jQuery (which works fine for both the image upload and after page refresh for the delete) is:

```
$('#file_upload').uploadifive({
    'uploadScript' : 'imageUpload.php',
    'removeCompleted' : true,
    'onUploadComplete' : function(file, data) {
        $('.display-images').append(data);
    }
});

$('.display-images img').each(function(){
    $(this).on('click', function(){
        var removeImg = $(this);
        var image = $(this).attr("src");
        var large = image.replace("tmp-images/", "").replace("-tb", "");
        var thumb = image.replace("tmp-images/", "");
        dataString = 'delete=1&large_image=' + large + '&thumb_image=' + thumb;
        $.ajax ({
            type: "GET",
            url: "deleteTempImage.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                if (data) {
                    $(removeImg).remove();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Please note that I will not just delete images using the click event handler in the long run, this is just for testing purposes until I get it working, after which I will use a more robust method.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you set the event delegation here is not proper. You need to change your code:

```
$('.display-images img').each(function(){
    $(this).on('click', function(){
        // Your code here
    });
});
```

to this

```
$('.display-images').on('click', 'img', function () {
    // Your code here
});
```

This will attach your event to any anchors within the `.display-images` element, 
reducing the scope of having to check the whole `document` element tree and increasing efficiency.

More info about it here:

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Thank you Palash, that worked a treat (I presumed I needed to use each() to assign the functionality to each image individually)

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it, you need to use delegation with .`on()`:

Here i'm using document as delegate. The proper way is to use the closest container element as delegate. So, if '.display-images' element(s) is/are not dynamic, use it as delegate.

```
$(document).on('click','.display-images img', function(){
    var removeImg = $(this);
    var image = $(this).attr("src");
    var large = image.replace("tmp-images/", "").replace("-tb", "");
    var thumb = image.replace("tmp-images/", "");
    dataString = 'delete=1&large_image=' + large + '&thumb_image=' + thumb;
    $.ajax ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "deleteTempImage.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            if (data) {
                $(removeImg).remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```